# How Parity-ethereum with --pruning fast handle ancient snapshots?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, parity-io

these are just 2 questions out of curiosity.

1. As of my understanding, in pruning mode fast, parity will sync all of the blocks in the ethereum blockchain and store in the local storage. However, it only sync recent snapshots and only them will be stored in the local storage. I am correct?
2. So what happened when I query historical snapshots that were not stored in the hard disk. Will parity take the oldest snapshot and blocks to calculate that ancient snapshots? Will it find an archive node and query that?